# remember location setting on iPhone for website

Tags: iphone, geolocation

In a native app, if a user tells their iPhone twice to allow the app to use location services, the phone won't ask again.  Is there a way to do this for a website/domain?

If someone goes to http://mydomain.com from a fresh start, they: 1 -get an alert for safari to use location service. 2 - get an alert for mydomain.com to use location services. Go to a second page and you get it again. Close the page and leave safari (go play angry birds like you do). Come back to mydomain.com in safari and it no longer asks if safari can use location services, but it again prompts twice for mydomain.com.

Is there a way to remember that the user has said it's okay to use location services for mydomain.com?

Thanks tons.
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

That would be the job of a cookie.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. any tips on that? what does the iphone need to find sitting inside a cookie to say "oh, it's cool. i don't need to keep asking for this domain." We can program something easy enough to prevent the request on the second page based on the session. It's when they close everything out and come back a week later. What do we need to have on an iPhone at that point? Thanks.

Comment: you'll want a persistent cookie as opposed to a session cookie : http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/persistent-cookies-used-for.html